# Complex SQL query with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
Sender

    | SenderKey | SenderGUID | 
    |-----------|------------|
    |     1     |     100    |
    |     2     |     101    |


Payment

    | SenderKey | PaymentGUID |    Date    |   Amount   | 
    |-----------|-------------|------------|------------|
    |     1     |     100     | 2015-03-09 |    4500    |
    |     2     |     101     | 2016-07-12 |    6000    |

Credit

    | SenderKey |   Amount   |    Date    | 
    |-----------|------------|------------|
    |     1     |    1000    | 2015-04-11 |
    |     2     |    3000    | 2016-06-03 |
```

I need to submit a SQL query that would yield a following result:

```
    | SenderGUID |   PaymentCount   |    CreditSum    | 
    |------------|------------------|-----------------|
    |     100    |        1         |       1000      |
    |     101    |        2         |       4500      |
```

Where `PaymentCount`stands for all payments made by a sender and should 1) count only those senders whose **first** payment was made after `2015-03-10`; 2)  that have made more than one payment.

In turns, `CreditSum` accounts for the amount of credit from `2015-03-10`.

I submit the following query to calculate PaymentCount:

```
SELECT Payment.SenderKey, COUNT(Payment.PaymentGuid) 
FROM Payment
WHERE (Payment.Date BETWEEN '2015-03-10' and NOW()) GROUP BY Payment.SenderKey
HAVING COUNT(Payment.PaymentGuid) > 1;
```

However, I am not sure how to account for the condition of the **first**. It seems that it has to be done using loops, but I am not sure how to use these in SQL.

Thanks.

Comment: The code is clearly MySQL, so I removed the SQL Server'ish tags.

Comment: Alexey, pls confirm your RDMS, is it MySQL or SQL Server which you had originally in tags.

Comment: I don't understand any of this it seems. You are showing two payment records of different senders. You only want senders that have made more than one payment. This is true for none of the senders, so I'd expect an empty result, but your result shows two rows. Then you only want senders whose first payment was made after 2015-03-10. This is true only for sender 2. Why is sender 1 in your results then? Then for sender 2 you have payment = 6000, credit = 3000. How do you get to a result CreditSum of 4500 then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only sends with the first payment after '2015-03-10', then all payments will be after that date.

So, move the date logic in the `where` to a `having` clause:

```
SELECT p.SenderKey, COUNT(p.PaymentGuid) 
FROM Payment p
GROUP BY p.SenderKey
HAVING COUNT(Payment.PaymentGuid) > 1 AND
       MIN(p.Date) >= '2015-03-10';
```

Note:  I'm assuming payments are not in the future, so the comparison to `NOW()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Subquery return SenderKeys which fulfill conditions:

-minimal payment date after 2015-03-10

-at least two payments

```
SELECT
Sender.SenderGUID,
COUNT(Payment.PaymentGuid) 
FROM
Sender
INNER JOIN 
Payment ON Sender.SenderKey = Payment.SenderKey
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SenderKey FROM Payment GROUP BY SenderKey
    HAVING MIN(Date) > '2015-03-10' AND COUNT(Payment.PaymentGuid) > 1
) MatchingSender ON MatchingSender.SenderKey = Payment.SenderKey
GROUP BY Sender.SenderGUID
```

Test code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5bcd9/1/0